# Lasso Regression in Sklearn Returning Inaccurate Coefficients

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to use sklearn and Lasso regression to do some analysis, but I'm getting some strange results. I've tried to narrow the problem, but it appears that the issue is that I just don't understand what sklearn is trying to do. For example, in the code below I would expect that the coefficient for 5th power of `x` to be 2. Or at least close to it. However, no matter what I do, I keep getting values around 16.

Any ideas about what I'm missing/doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso    

x_data = np.reshape(np.linspace(-3, 3, 20), (-1, 1))
y_data = 2*x_data**5   # + np.random.normal(0, 2, x_data.shape)

X = np.hstack((np.ones(x_data.shape), x_data, x_data**2, x_data*3, x_data**4, x_data*5))

c5 = list()

for alpha in np.logspace(0, 2, num=100):
    model = Lasso(alpha=alpha, max_iter=15000, fit_intercept=True, warm_start=False, selection='cyclic', tol=1e-5)
    model.fit(X, y_data)
    coefficient = model.coef_[-1]
    c5.append(coefficient)


fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.logspace(0, 2, num=100).tolist(), c5, 'r-')
plt.xlabel('x data')
plt.ylabel('y data')
plt.grid(True)
fig.canvas.manager.window.raise_()
plt.show()
```

[image: $$\alpha$$ vs C5]

Comment: `X = np.hstack((np.ones(x_data.shape), x_data, x_data**2, x_data*3, x_data**4, x_data*5))` - I guess this should be `x_data**3` and `x_data**5`